# How to use " and ' single quote and double quote filtering in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I want to make a function where special character's should be filtered out. Like if user type anything on text Area if he/she enters the special Character's then it will throw and alert popup.Now it was working for almost all the character's except single and double quotes i want to include that also [ " and ' ]. Can anyone help me with this.
thank you so much!!!

```
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        guard var textViewText = textView.text else {
            return
        }
        var specialCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "₹!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]|<>?;=-")
        specialCharacterSet.insert(charactersIn: "'")
        

        if let range = textViewText.rangeOfCharacter(from: specialCharacterSet) {
            textViewText = textViewText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "")
            textView.text = textViewText

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Special characters are not allowed!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `specialCharacterSet.insert(charactersIn: "'\"")`? But is your issue related to add double quotes, or because there are "multiples single & double quotes" look alike? Like `‘ « “ ´ »` etc.?

Comment: To avoid escaping special characters you can use the *Raw String Syntax* `#"` and `"#`

Comment: i want if i type ' or " and all others special character's also then it should check that if textarea have this ' or " not if there is any of this character's available than alert should show but now single and double quote is not working rest are working

Comment: Maybe it would be easier/clearer to work with character sets for the characters you allow.

Answer (score 0):

use this method, also I have share screenshot for reference (debug)

```
func setText()
{
    var textViewText = self.txtview?.text ?? ""
    let specialCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "₹!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]|<>?;=-'\"")
    
    if let range = textViewText.rangeOfCharacter(from: specialCharacterSet) {
        textViewText = textViewText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "")
        self.txtview?.text = textViewText
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Special characters are not allowed!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry to say but not working this one

Comment: check my answer again I have updated it.

Comment: still not working (- -)

Comment: @SanjugSonowal can you share code on github, let me check